# HTTP Status 404-The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

few months ago i've worked on this project for my university (a quiz game) and all was fine! Now i've re-opened the eclipse project but i don't know why, it doesn't work! I've already searched in the old topic, because i know this is a recurrent problem, but i don't know how to solve it! I think is just a configuration problem because i've wrote the entire project on another workstation and there all was fine. Now i'm trying to run the servlet on my Mac with Eclipse Mars and tomcat 8.0.

Here i report the code of one of my servlet and the xml file.

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DbHelper;

/**
* Servlet implementation class Login
*/
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private DbHelper dbHelper = null;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    String driver = context.getInitParameter("dbDriver");
    String path = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
    String user = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
    String pass = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");

    try {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(driver, path, user, pass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    if(dbHelper!=null){
        try {
            dbHelper.destroy();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();

    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");


    try {if (dbHelper.isPlayer(username, password)){
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        response.sendRedirect("Player");

    } else
        if (dbHelper.isAuthor(username, password)){ 
            session.setAttribute("username",username);
            response.sendRedirect("Author");

        }else{
            request.setAttribute("error", 1);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.sendRedirect("html/error.html");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}

}
```

The XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0"
metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>CheckMyBrain</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
<description>Database URL</description>
<param-name>dbUrl</param-name>
<param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Quiz</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>Database user</description>
<param-name>dbUser</param-name>
<param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>Database password</description>
<param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
<param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>Database driver</description>
<param-name>dbDriver</param-name>
<param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>smtpHost</param-name>
<param-value>smtp.gmail.com</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>smtpPort</param-name>
<param-value>587</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
 <param-name>smtpUser</param-name>
<param-value>checkmybrain37@gmail.com</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>smtpPass</param-name>
<param-value>stosultomcat</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

[folders here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxm5j.png)

Tomcat location is not on workspace metadata.

[When i run the Servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPz9j.png)

Comment: Who/what/when is giving you the 404?

Comment: This is a servlet based web application, the servlet container is giving him a 404